# Scala Huygens Fokker (command line only) v1.88b unfortunately removes extra spaces

Tags: batch-file

The batch code:

```
scala.exe --SET SYNTH 117^
          --LOAD /MAPPING \"My mapping\"^
          --LOAD \"Intonation        with extra spaces\"^
          --SEND /FILE \"Test\"^
          --EXIT
```

It gives me output:

```
Intonation with extra spaces.scl not found or not a scale file
```

With the batch code:

```
scala.exe --SET SYNTH 117^
          --LOAD /MAPPING \"My mapping\"^
          --LOAD \"Intonation without extra spaces\"^
          --SEND /FILE \"test\"^
          --EXIT
```

Works Correctly.

How can I tell the batch not to ignore the extra spaces?

Comment: If the quotes are part of the argument then use `--LOAD "\"Intonation        with extra spaces\""^` else simply remove the quote escaping backslashes

Comment: I agree with the above comment. I wouldn't have thought that there was any need to escape any of the doublequotes at all. You would be more likely to need to escape them as internal doublequotes if all of the arguments were passed as one long doublequoted string to `scala`.

Comment: @RiccardoLaMarca, what doesn't work.  You were given two things to try. I don't see anything in the documentation about using backslashes.

Comment: @MC ND Unfortunately   --LOAD "\"Intonation with extra spaces\""^    doesn't work. Sorry.

Comment: The documentation I read on the developers website doesn't mention anything about using a backslash at all and it does say that file names should be quoted to protect special character. So using the **K.I.S.S.** analogy I would use `--LOAD /MAPPING "C:\my path\my map.kbm"` and `--LOAD "C:\my path\my scale file.scl"`

Comment: Even this solution does not work.

Comment: From the website: **Contact the author in the event of questions or problems.** **Scala was created by Manuel Op de Coul in the Netherlands. E-mail: coul@huygens-fokker.org**

Comment: I have contact the autor and his has release a new version of Scala for solved my problem and now the code works also more simplified!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Manuel Op de Coul (coul@huygens-fokker.org) and his has released a new version of Scala for solved my problem and now the code works also more simplified!!!

```
scala.exe   --SET SYNTH 117^
            --LOAD/MAPPING "My mapping"^
            --LOAD "Intonation        with extra spaces"^
            --SEND/FILE "Test"^
            --EXIT
```

Yours is the correct answer, @Squashman!

Answer (score 0):

It is not `scala.exe`, but using a simple command line argument dump tool we get

```
W:\>type 56190749.cmd
vcCmdLine.exe --SET SYNTH 117^
              --LOAD /MAPPING \"My mapping\"^
              --LOAD \"Intonation        with extra spaces\"^
              --SEND /FILE \"Test\"^
              --EXIT
W:\>56190749.cmd

W:\>vcCmdLine.exe --SET SYNTH 117              --LOAD /MAPPING \"My mapping\"              --LOAD \"Intonation        with extra spaces\"              --SEND /FILE \"Test\"              --EXIT
cmdline:[vcCmdLine.exe  --SET SYNTH 117              --LOAD /MAPPING \"My mapping\"              --LOAD \"Intonation        with extra spaces\"              --SEND /FILE \"Test\"              --EXIT]

arg_000:[vcCmdLine.exe]
arg_001:[--SET]
arg_002:[SYNTH]
arg_003:[117]
arg_004:[--LOAD]
arg_005:[/MAPPING]
arg_006:["My]
arg_007:[mapping"]
arg_008:[--LOAD]
arg_009:["Intonation]
arg_010:[with]
arg_011:[extra]
arg_012:[spaces"]
arg_013:[--SEND]
arg_014:[/FILE]
arg_015:["Test"]
arg_016:[--EXIT]

W:\>
```

A simplification on quote escaping gives

```
W:\>type 56190749.cmd
vcCmdLine.exe --SET SYNTH 117^
              --LOAD /MAPPING "My mapping"^
              --LOAD "Intonation        with extra spaces"^
              --SEND /FILE "Test"^
              --EXIT
W:\>56190749.cmd

W:\>vcCmdLine.exe --SET SYNTH 117              --LOAD /MAPPING "My mapping"              --LOAD "Intonation        with extra spaces"              --SEND /FILE "Test"              --EXIT
cmdline:[vcCmdLine.exe  --SET SYNTH 117              --LOAD /MAPPING "My mapping"              --LOAD "Intonation        with extra spaces"              --SEND /FILE "Test"              --EXIT]

arg_000:[vcCmdLine.exe]
arg_001:[--SET]
arg_002:[SYNTH]
arg_003:[117]
arg_004:[--LOAD]
arg_005:[/MAPPING]
arg_006:[My mapping]
arg_007:[--LOAD]
arg_008:[Intonation        with extra spaces]
arg_009:[--SEND]
arg_010:[/FILE]
arg_011:[Test]
arg_012:[--EXIT]

W:\>
```

If the double quotes are needed inside the arguments, then we can use

```
W:\>type 56190749.cmd
vcCmdLine.exe --SET SYNTH 117^
              --LOAD /MAPPING "\"My mapping\""^
              --LOAD "\"Intonation        with extra spaces\""^
              --SEND /FILE "\"Test\""^
              --EXIT
W:\>56190749.cmd

W:\>vcCmdLine.exe --SET SYNTH 117              --LOAD /MAPPING "\"My mapping\""              --LOAD "\"Intonation        with extra spaces\""              --SEND /FILE "\"Test\""              --EXIT
cmdline:[vcCmdLine.exe  --SET SYNTH 117              --LOAD /MAPPING "\"My mapping\""              --LOAD "\"Intonation        with extra spaces\""              --SEND /FILE "\"Test\""              --EXIT]

arg_000:[vcCmdLine.exe]
arg_001:[--SET]
arg_002:[SYNTH]
arg_003:[117]
arg_004:[--LOAD]
arg_005:[/MAPPING]
arg_006:["My mapping"]
arg_007:[--LOAD]
arg_008:["Intonation        with extra spaces"]
arg_009:[--SEND]
arg_010:[/FILE]
arg_011:["Test"]
arg_012:[--EXIT]

W:\>
```

Of course `scala.exe` could have some particular behaviour, but this is one way to start trying.

Comment: Unfortunately don't work. I will contact the autor like suggested by Squashman. Thank you anyway